# Phonegap : How to make a circle mask before to take a picture?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am doing an android and iOS application thanks to Phonegap and jQuery mobile. I have a registration part where members must take a picture of themselves. And I would like to display a round shape onto the camera to get an overview of this photo and have the person centered in the round picture.

Is there a plugin to display (before taking a picture) a mask when the camera is on?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there. Re your deleted post just now, "doesn't work" and "big problems" are not error reports we can advise upon. Please offer error messages, logs, code or database rows etc - and be detailed about what you've done to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I created a face detect plugin, maybe it can help you

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/faceDetect

It returns the face rectangle after taking the picture, but I think you can use it to center tehe photo